# storing specific element in knockout.js viewmodel (array)

Tags: javascript, c#, mvvm, knockout.js

I want to parse specific element from an existing viewModel and put it into a new array.

I have an applications viewModel which has tons of information of applicants. It is called in the following way:

```
 self.applications = ko.observableArray(@Html.Json(Model.ApplicationCompatibilities.Select(o => o.JsonForm)) || []);
```

[image]

So the "application" object has several elements in it as shown in the attached image above.

What I wanted to do was, I wanted to retrieve only the "applicationKey" element into a new array. So what I did was :

```
            self.previewApplication = ko.computed(function () {
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.applications(), function (i) {
                    return i.application.applicationKey;
                });
            });
```

I intended to loop through the "self.applications()" viewModel and return only the "application.applicationKey". But what I actually get by doing that is:

[image]

I am just getting the same "applications" object inside the new viewModel. 
How can I get an array of only the "application.applicationKey" ?

Thanks! Please Help!

EDIT:

This works now! Now my viewModel.previewApplication() gives me a list of applicationKey's. Now what I want to do is, I want to add a link that loads a modal. And inside that modal I want to display the specific "application" that has a specific "applicationKey"

For example, the link to the modal will look like this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewApplicantModal" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }">
     Preview Application
</a>
```

So If I inspect the element of the link, it has a new data-binding:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewApplicantModal" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }" data-applicationkey="abc976cfx">
    Preview Application
</a>
```

Finally I want to loop through the "application" object and return only "one" element of the object that has "abc976cfx" as its applicationKey.

Is there an easy way of doing this? I attached a screenshot for better explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayFilter` filters the array and the function returns true or false if the item matches your filter criteria or not.  You want `arrayMap` instead.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use it in this specific case?

Comment: Literally replace `arrayFilter` with `arrayMap`, everything else remains the same.  The function for `arrayMap` returns whatever you want to map the item to, in this case a scalar value.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Will you be able to answer my 2nd connecting question? Please take a look at my Edit if possible. Thank you so much!

Comment: Per site rules, additional questions should be submitted separately (but you can link back to the original); no one is going to look at a question that is marked as answered so you're killing your chances at getting an answer.